# How to use the same input twice or more

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Heres My Code

```
 void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        ContinueDialog();
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

}
```

I wanna use the space input twice or more to access my other function is there a way?

Comment: add a loop inside the if statement that runs two or three times

Comment: or are you trying to access the space_down event?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same function other places in your code. The Input.GetKeyDown() function returns true for the first frame the key is pressed, as seen here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i got your question right but i try to help you :)

You can do it this way :

```
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        ContinueDialog();
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        OtherMethod();
    }

}
```

Or what i prefer use the other method in the same if statment:

```
void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            OtherMethod();
            ContinueDialog();
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options to perform additional actions.

You can add a loop inside your if statement:

```
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        int count = 1;
        while(count < <desired number of iterations>){
            ContinueDialog();
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use a loop with a switch: void Update() {

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        int count = 1;
        while(count < <desired number of iterations>)
        {
            switch(count)
            {
                case 1: 
                    ContinueDialog();
                    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
                    count++;
                    break;

                case 2: 
                    otherFunction();
                    count++;
                    break;

                case 3: 
                    thirdFunction();
                    count++;
                    break;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

You can handle the input.KeyDown event with a custom handler.